# my alert box adding unncessory space on top and bottom android

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert)
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            }
            builder.setTitle("Alert")
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setNegativeButton("Ok") { dialog, which -> }
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
```

[image]

Comment: Which OS version run on your device ?

Comment: my device has Marshmello OS

Comment: i got man its becz of them thanks

Comment: Did you override the dialog theme in your theme resource file (often called style.xml) ?

Comment: no man i am not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` with `R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert`, this will allow you to skip `SDK_INT` check and you won't be relying on `android.R` which is not guaranteed to be uniform across all devices.